# Check if another webpage is loaded in React JS, to redirect later

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, fetch, load

So I am redirecting users to dynamic IP Urls in React, the IPs are generated by the backend servers and work just fine!

The issue here is that it takes time to load in servers and when the user is redirected to that particular room, it shows a 404 not found error for the next 10 - 15 seconds and if you refresh the page after that particular time, the page will be loaded.

I tried adding a fetch request to the URL and once it returns the status as 200, I will then stop the spinner and redirect to that URL, but the status never shows 200.

```
let res = await fetch(`http://${ipAddress}`, {'mode': 'no-cors'});
while(res.status === 0) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    res = await fetch(`http://${ipAddress}`, {'mode': 'no-cors'});
}
if(res.status === 200) {
   setSpinner(false);
   window.open(`http://${ipAddress}`);
}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

**EDIT:**

When I console log the res variable in the while loop:

```
body: null
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers
    __proto__: Headers
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
```

Comment: have you checked that you are only getting status `0` and `200`

Comment: @Dalvik I am only getting status 0